# Salary comes from salt, but where does salt come from?

Tags: vocabulary

OK, this was a trick question. :-) The first part of the question is about etymology but my real question is about vocabulary. I would like to know the name of the place where sea salt is harvested. Is there a specific name for it in English?

I have found salt pan - alluding to the technique of boiling sea water in a pan to collect the salt at the end - or salt (evaporation) pond.

In Portuguese we have the single word "salina" to define such place.

Comment: I've always heard them called *salt ponds*.

Comment: My translator goes from Portuguese "salina" to English "salt mine".

Comment: Bonaire has incredible [salt flats](http://archive.audubonmagazine.org/web/bonaire/) (also called pans)

Comment: OT but does salary really come from salt? The only confirmation is Pliny repeating a story that soldiers were paid in salt ?

Comment: @mgb That's the story I've heard too and it seems to be the general accepted theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Saltings' or [salterns](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saltern?showCookiePolicy=true) are probably closest, but neither is really in common use: in Britain coastal saltworks were largely put out of business in the 19th century by a combination of taxation and the Cheshire mines.[1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saltern?showCookiePolicy=true)